# ksoap2 blackberry webservice problem, sample need

Tags: web-services, parsing, blackberry, ksoap2

I'm new in blackberry, Currently I'm working at a program, in which I'm fetching data from the php based web service using ksoap2 lib. Everything works smoothly. App connects and fetches the data from the webservice, But now the problem is that, I don't know how to parse the resulting data. It is complex data and contains many rows and values. Previously I used the ksoap lib in Android and it worked very well, But now it is not working. I debug the app and make sure that web service is returning correct data. So I need a help in getting the data from the resulting object. How to do it. I searched the net, but most example are based on single returning string, But I need a complex data arraylist returning example. Anyone can help?
Here is the returned data sample

```
 [unnamed_struct_use_soapval{id=62; email_address=a@a.com; name=xyz; password=abc; user_type_id=2; annual_expiry=null;}]
```

and here is the code which I'm using to parse the resulting data.

```
 ht.call(soapAction, envelope);
 String result = (envelope.getResult()).toString();
 SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP =(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;             
 int count = ((SoapObject) resultsRequestSOAP).getPropertyCount();
```

don't know how to proceed further. Wasted already 3-4 days on it and still didn't find anything useful. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
String email_address= response.getProperty("email_address").toString();
```